# When I add headers with an HttpInterceptor they are added to lazyUpdate, not the headers array

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I have added an authorization header via an HttpInterceptor in Angular, but the output doesn't seem correct. Based on the JSON output after the header has been added this feels far too unwieldy to be correct Am I adding headers incorrectly, or am I accessing them wrong?:

```
headers["lazyUpdate"].forEach(x=>{x.name=='Authorization'}).value
```

Goal is to return `Bearer mystring`

interceptor called:

> {"url":"https://myurl","body:{}, "reportProgress":false,
>   "withCredentials":false,
>   "responseType":"json",
>   "method":"POST",
>   "headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"myurl"}

token.interceptor.ts:13 interceptor added token:

> {"url":"myurl",
>   "body":{},
>   "reportProgress":false,
>   "withCredentials":false,
>   "responseType":"json",
>   "method":"POST",
>   "headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":[**{"name":"Authorization","value":"Bearer mystring","op":"s"}**],
>   "headers":{},"lazyInit":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":{}},"urlWithParams":"myurl"}

My TokenInterceptor class:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {   
    console.log('interceptor called: '+JSON.stringify(request))

    let r = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("id_token")}`)
    });
    console.log('interceptor added token: '+JSON.stringify(r))
    return next.handle(r);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `headers.append()` instead of `headers.set()`

Comment: @Chaitanya tried that with no luck

Comment: Ever solve this?

Comment: @Chris I just looked back at my code and it appears I used Chaitanya solution... not sure why I thought it didnt work when I tired, but it works in production now.